# Windbg .thread command is useless?

Tags: windbg, kernel

The ".thread" command is used to change the thread context in Windows kernel debugging.
[MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-thread--set-register-context-)

But I encountered the below situation:

1. Execute the following two commands consecutively.
   The first command set thread context to ffffc08213599040, but it Actually still ffffc08229313080.

```
0: kd> .thread ffffc082`13599040          
Implicit thread is now ffffc082`13599040
0: kd> .thread
Implicit thread is now ffffc082`29313080
```

2.Execute the following two commands consecutively. I want to change the rip of the thread ffffc08213599040, But command "r rip=xxx" failed.

```
0: kd> .thread ffffc082`13599040
Implicit thread is now ffffc082`13599040
0: kd> r rip = fffff803`3de6341d
Last set context:
                               ^ Bad register error in 'r rip = fffff803`3de6341d'
```

Answer (score 4):

It works As Expected and Documented
Running a plain .thread resets context to CurrentThread as documented

```
Quote From Documentation  

Thread 
The address of the thread. If this is omitted or zero,   
the thread context is reset to the current thread.
```

You Cannot Set @rip to Arbitrary Values

Comment: Okay, I didn’t notice "If omitted or zero,
The thread context will be reset to the current thread. "
But why can't I use the command r to set the register value?

Comment: The rip value can be modified in windbg.